# Add classpath to folder containing property files in Maven

Tags: classpath, maven

I have a property file which is not located in a classpath in Maven.

Therefore I can't reach it with:

ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PROPS_FILE);

How can I add the folder containing the property file to the classpath, so it will be available during build and test of the project?

Answer (score 4):

Just add the file into the resources folder under src/main maven project. i did that and works like a charm.

hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Under the  task you can add a set of resources and testResources like so:

```
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>somedir</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>

  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>test/unit</directory>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
```

They also allow you to define exclusion and inclusion rules. This is very powerful for a legacy code base but for new code bases, you should follow the [maven's standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) to avoid lots of custom definitions in your POM files.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to put that file under correct location in Maven like either src/main/resources and/or src/test/resources depending where it will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't like Maven's enforcement of certain directories, use the [build-helper plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) to add your own directory to the classpath as generated by "mvn eclipse:eclipse".